# findPreference null on specific tablet

Tags: java, android, tablet

On my google play error reporting page, there are error regarding NPE and it's only on tablets such as ASUS Transformer Pad TF300T and other Tablet S.

```
findPreference("setting").setOnPreferenceClickListener(
```

Is there anyway to make findPreference works on tablet?

Comment: this is your preference.. did you ensure it was created?

Comment: @Tan Jit Ren Make sure you add the sufficient code which can be understandable and briefly describe your issue also .

Comment: Basically my code doesn't crash on all android handheld smartphone, except on tablet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of problem. Seems like tablet above 3.0 you have to put findPreference into each Fragment, not on the preferenceActivity. otherwise they crashed.